# AJAX request becomes invalid due to prepending of URL before sent to server

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, http

I have a problem with my ajax requests to an api controller in ASP.NET MVC 5.

My scenario is like this:

I have an api controller like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/organizations/{orgId:int}/students")]
class StudentController{

        [Route("subjects")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetSubjects(int orgId)
        {
        }

}
```

And in my .js file I have a code for calling that request with the specified url like this:

```
var baseURL = "api/organizations/" + $("#orgId").val() + "/students";

$.get(baseURL + "/subjects").done(function (subjects) {
            $.each(subjects, function (index, val) {

                var vm = new SubjectVM();

                vm.Id(val.Id);
                vm.Name(val.Name);

                self.Subjects.push(vm);
            });
        });
```

But the problem is it will not go into that controller method because its url looks like this http://localhost:10927/students/api/organizations/15/students/subjects

What it should be is like this http://localhost:10927/api/organizations/15/students/subjects so that it will go in.

What I'm confused of was when I'm in the student main page with url like this http://localhost:10927, all is well. The url it produced is correct. But when I'm on the http://localhost:10927/student/create page it will produced the said url.

Does anyone here have an idea of what was happening? Hopefully you can help me here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `baseURL` variable to start with a forward slash: `/`
Doing this forces the URL to be built from the root of the host, rather than the current directory.